# socket.io emit to default room does not work

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-1.0

When I call emit without the io.emit() all the connected clients receive the message as you would expect.  However when trying to send a message to the default room using io.to(socket.id).emit(), the client does not receive the message.

Refering to default room documentation at
http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#default-room

Using nodejs `v4.2.6`

Client:

```
var socket = io();
socket.on('connect', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/some-path',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {socket_id: socket.id},
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Server:

```
app.post('/some-path', function(req, res) {
  var socketID = req.body.socket_id;
  io.to(socketID).emit('message', {'message': socketID});
  res.end(socketID);
});
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant code.  Sending to rooms works just fine in socket.io when done correctly so clearly this has to be something with YOUR code.  Questions about code MUST include the relevant code.  How are we to know what you did wrong in your code if you don't include it?

Comment: Thank you @jfriend00, I think your suggestion will make a big difference in understanding what I found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct solution. It was discovered that the default room socket.id being used by the server to set the default room is not the same as the client socket.id. Please advise.

On the **client** if you evaluate `socket.id` you get something like, `v4eEdSX5RnDSXjzuAAAA`

On the **server** in, `io.on('connection', function(socket){})` if you evaluate `socket.id` you will get something like, `/#v4eEdSX5RnDSXjzuAAAA`.
Notice the **/#** prepended to the client socket.id.

So you have two ways of solving this issue

1. When calling emit prepend `/#` to the socket ID
2. Override the io "connection" listener to set the room to the socket ID without the `/#` prepended

Selected option two is as follows:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socketID = socket.client.id;
  socket.join(socketID);
  console.log('a user connected ' + socketID);
});
```

Comment: Its dumb that socket ids are being used as default rooms with no way to configure it turned off.